# Как разделить строки до и после знака python

Tags: python-3.x, массивы

Строки разделяются, но при выводе показываются только то что было до символа. Код:

```
file = open("accs.txt", "r")
lines = file.read()
a = lines.split(":")
print("Массив - 0")
print(a[0])
print("Массив - 1")
print(a[1])
```

Что выводится:

```
Массив - 0
thisyuyun@yahoo.com
Массив - 1
so618618
rasyidulkhair@gmail.com
```

Чего я пытаюсь добиться:

```
Массив - 0
thisyuyun@yahoo.com (почта)
Массив - 1
so618618 (пароль)
```

Comment: а что в самом файле находится вы бы тоже привели бы для лучшего понимания

Comment: А на строки кто бить будет? А то вы разбили по двоеточиям, и у вас вышло: a[0] - содержит кусок первой строки до двоеточия, a[1] - содержит кусок первой строки после двоеточия плюс перевод строки плюс кусок второй строки до двоеточия, a[2] - содержит кусок второй строки после двоеточия плюс перевод строки плюс кусок третьей строки до двоеточия, и т.д.

Comment: thisyuyun@yahoo.com:125581
sophieevolet@gmail.com:so618618

Answer (score 1):

у вас в файле несколько строк, которые тоже надо разбить через разделитель, поэтому лучше сделать так:

```
lines = file.readlines() # считываем файл построчно

for line in lines:
    data = line[:-1].split(':') # -1, чтобы отрезать в конце строки перевод каретки
    print(f'почта: {data[0]}, пароль: {data[1]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать конструкцию `with`

```
def main():
    with open("accs.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.read().split('\n')

        a = []
        for line in lines:
            gmail, password = line.split(":")
            a.append((gmail, password))

        print("Массив - 0")
        print(a[0])
        print("Массив - 1")
        print(a[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Также, возможно, для дальнейшего удобство в массиве `a` стоит хранить пару (почта, пароль), вместо их чередования. Таким образом, массив становится более однородным.

Вместо этого

```
a.append(gmail)
a.append(password)
```

это

```
a.append((gmail, password))
```

В таком случае вывод программы:

```
Массив - 0
('thisyuyun@yahoo.com', 'so618618')
Массив - 1
('lol@yahoo.com', 'kek618618')
```